# Android: Multiple galleries in listview

Tags: android, listview, gallery

I am battling to implement multiple galleries inside a listview.

The listview has an adapter(BaseAdapter) which populates the list with data.
The adapter consists of a textview (which specifies the name of the gallery) and a gallery.
Within this adapter I instantiate the Gallery object and attach a new adapter (which populates the gallery with images) to the gallery object.

The problem is as follows:
Each row is populated with a name and a gallery object - this works fine.
But each gallery only has one image as opposed to the 10 images (test data).

Code snippets:

**Adapter for populating the listview**

```
public class Adapter_GalleryList extends BaseAdapter
{
private static final String ERRORTAG = "ERROR_CHECKING --> ";   


//Components
private Context context;


//Global variables
private Object_Event[] events;


public Adapter_GalleryList(Context context, Object_Event[] events)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.events = events;
}


public int getCount()
{
    return events.length;
}


public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return position;
}


public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //Inflate the each row of the list with the gallerylist layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_gallerylist, parent , false);


    //Configure a typeface for the text headings
    Typeface quackery = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/tpf_quackery.ttf");


    //Instantiate the row's components
    TextView textEventName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
    Gallery eventGallery = (Gallery) rowView.findViewById(R.id.gallery);


    //Populate the components with data
    textEventName.setTypeface(quackery);
    textEventName.setText(events[position].Name);


    Integer[] images = new Integer[10]; 
    images[0] = R.drawable.button_events;
    images[1] = R.drawable.button_events;
    images[2] = R.drawable.button_events;
    images[3] = R.drawable.button_events;
    images[4] = R.drawable.button_events;
    images[5] = R.drawable.button_events;
    images[6] = R.drawable.button_events;
    images[7] = R.drawable.button_events;
    images[8] = R.drawable.button_events;
    images[9] = R.drawable.button_events;

    Adapter_EventGallery adapter = new Adapter_EventGallery(context,images);
    eventGallery.setAdapter(adapter);


    //OnClickListener for images in the gallery
    eventGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



    return rowView;
}
}
```

**Adapter for populating the independent galleries**

```
public class Adapter_EventGallery extends BaseAdapter
{
private static final String ERRORTAG = "ERROR_CHECKING --> ";

//Component variables
    private Context adapterContext;



private Integer[] images;


public Adapter_EventGallery(Context passedContext, Integer[] images)
{
    adapterContext = passedContext;
    this.images = images;
}


public int getCount()
{
    Log.i(ERRORTAG, "Length: " + images.length);
    return images.length;
}


public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return position;
}


public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    Log.i(ERRORTAG, "EventGallery Position: " + position);

    ImageView galleryImage = new ImageView(adapterContext);

    galleryImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    galleryImage.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(250, 250));
    galleryImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    //galleryImage.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

    return galleryImage;
}
```

}

Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: I'd try different images

Comment: @ChenKinnrot, the images are merely a test and different images shouldn't make a difference.  I will attach an image of the screen to give more insight to the problem.

Comment: Dont have enough rep to add images. Alternatively find image here: http://tinypic.com/r/2rdalia/6

Comment: I mean in the app, maybe cause it's all the same resource you see only one...

Comment: Is the getView() of Adapter_EventGallery called only once per row? Could you show the rest of this adapter class?

Comment: @ChenKinnrot, I had tested the implementation with the same image test data outside of a listview and it seemed to work.

Comment: @KarolGusak, the getView() method seems to be called multiple times - I checked using Log outputs.  I provided the full code as requested

Comment: @KarolGusak, you seem to be onto something here.

The "inner" adapter (adapter for the gallery) only calls the getView() method once.  The "outer" adapter (adapter for the list) calls the getView() method multiple times.

So the problem is, why is the getView() method for the gallery adapter only called once per row?

Comment: I do not know the Gallery component frankly. If you set it up exactly as you do now, but without using the outer adapter (i.e have a screen with just one gallery component), does it display all the items?

Comment: Yes, it displays all the images and works perfectly fine. Thats the odd thing I couldn't understand either.  For some reason it only calls the getView() method once per row.

Comment: I think the Gallery component does not span horizontally through the available screen space. Is it set to `match_parent` in the layout? Could you show your layouts as well?

Comment: @KarolGusak, that was the problem. Thank you for your help. I don't know how to mark your comment as the answer so answered the question myself and mentioned you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of KarolGusak I managed to fix the problem.
The problem was in fact that the Gallery did not span the entire width as Karol Gusak pointed out.

A rookie mistake...